# how to remove spacing inbetween addtext function using phpword

Tags: phpword

I have the following code but i cannot figure out how to remove the line space or set custom line height etc.

```
require_once '/opt/html/paradox/protected/extensions/PHPWord/src/PhpWord/Autoloader.php';
        \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader::register();
        $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();


        $filename = "Weekly-Report - " . date('d F Y') ;


        // adding the necessary font styles
        $phpWord->addFontStyle('font_default', array('name'=>'HelveticaNeueLT Std Lt', 'size'=>11, 'color'=>'000000'));

        $phpWord->addFontStyle('font_h2', array('name'=>'HelveticaNeueLT Std Med', 'size'=>14, 'color'=>'6D6D6D'));
        $phpWord->addFontStyle('font_h3', array('name'=>'HelveticaNeueLT Std Med', 'size'=>12, 'color'=>'949494'));

        //adding the necessary header/title styles
        $phpWord->addTitleStyle(1, array('name'=>'Cambria (Headings)', 'size'=>16, 'align'=>'center','underline'=>'UNDERLINE_SINGLE')); //h1
        //$phpWord->addTitleStyle(2, "font_h2"); //h2
        //$phpWord->addTitleStyle(3, "font_h3"); //h3

        //adding the necessary paragraph styles
        $phpWord->addParagraphStyle('paragraph_default', array('spaceBefore' => 0, 'spaceAfter' => 0));
        $paragraphOptions = array( 
                'spaceBefore' => 0, 'spaceAfter' => 0
        );

        $fontStyleSubHeading = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font();
        $fontStyleSubHeading->setBold(true);
        $fontStyleSubHeading->setName('Calibri');
        $fontStyleSubHeading->setSize(11);

        //############################### STARTING DOCUMENT AND DEFINING STYLES ###############################

        /* Note: any element you append to a document must reside inside of a Section. */
        $section = $phpWord->addSection();


        $section->addTitle(
                htmlspecialchars('Weekly Multi-Client Project Status Report '. date('d/M/Y'))
        );



        //$myTextElement->setFontStyle($fontStyleHeading);


        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->select = "PROJECT, PERCENT, ExpectedCompletionDate, PROJINFO";
        $criteria->compare('NES',1);
        $criteria->addCondition('PERCENT < 100');
        $criteria->compare('PROJCODE','W');
        $criteria->compare('deleted','0');
        $projects = Projects::model()->findAll($criteria);

        foreach ($projects as $project) {

            $myTextElement = $section->addText(
                    htmlspecialchars($project->PROJECT . ":")

            );
            $myTextElement->setFontStyle($fontStyleSubHeading);

            // Adding Text element to the Section having font styled by default...
            $percent = round($project->PERCENT,2);
            $section->addText(
                    htmlspecialchars('Total % Complete - '.$percent),
                    $paragraphOptions
            );

            $section->addText(
                    htmlspecialchars($project->PROJINFO)
            );

            $myTextElement = $section->addText(
                    htmlspecialchars('Action items for SI')
            );
            $myTextElement->setFontStyle($fontStyleSubHeading);
            $section->addText(
                    htmlspecialchars('None')
            );          


            $myTextElement = $section->addText(
                    htmlspecialchars('Action items for MC')
            );
            $myTextElement->setFontStyle($fontStyleSubHeading);
            $section->addText(
                    htmlspecialchars('None')
            );

        }
```

It should be a title and each for each section should be spaced apart and all the lines within shoudl have no spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving the paragraph options incorrectly to the $section->addText() function. The second parameter is font styling, i.e. you need to update the function call to:

```
 $section->addText(
     htmlspecialchars('Total % Complete - '.$percent),
     null,
     $paragraphOptions
 );
```

Updated:

to use both your font style and paragraph style, you can give them both as parameters instead of using the setFontStyle function (i.e. you shouldn't have the need for the $myTextElement variable at all when giving the styles as parameters when needed):

```
 $fontStyle = array('name' => 'Calibri', 'size' => 11, 'bold' => true);

 $section->addText(
     htmlspecialchars('Action items for SI'),
     $fontStyle,
     $paragraphOptions
 );
```

Comment: how to i get it to work with `$fontStyleSubHeading` and `$myTextElement`

Comment: updated the answer, i.e. if I understood your case correctly, you don't actually need the $myTextElement variable